# How do i add New column in Dataframe with multiple string values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

For example I want to add a New Column called as DFA with a large number of string values like `http://...URL` links.

Basically add a new column with multiple values.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import os,sys
from os import path
import re
import sys, ast
import subprocess
import numpy as np
#from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',1000)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.notebook_repr_html', True)


location = "/root/madhu_test/bpstest/results/finalnss.txt"

f = pd.read_csv(location,delimiter='\t\t',skiprows=2)


cols = f.columns.tolist()
print cols
f = f.drop('BPS Profile.2', 1)
f = f.drop('BPS Profile.1', 1)
np.radians(f['Throughput'])
np.radians(f['Throughput.1'])
f.Throughput = f.Throughput.round()
f['Throughput.1'] = f['Throughput.1'].round()
f['percentage'] = ((f['Throughput.1']-f['Throughput'])/f['Throughput.1'])*100.0
f['percentage.1'] = ((f['Throughput.2']-f['Throughput'])/f['Throughput.2'])*100.0
f['Throughput.2'] = f['Throughput.2'].round()

f.percentage = f.percentage.round(1)
f['percentage.1'] = f['percentage.1'].round(1)
f['DFA'].loc = [['<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>','<a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>']]
```

Gives output

```
                                                                    DFA
0    SigTestHTTP21kBin         217           219           453         0.9          52.0  [<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>, <a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>]
1   SigTestHTTP21kHtml         359           364           372         1.4           3.4  [<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>, <a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>]
2   SigTestHTTP21kText         380           376           378        -1.1          -0.6  [<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>, <a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>]
3     NSS-HTTP21Kdelay         378           380           378         0.5           0.0  [<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>, <a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>]
4          NSS-HTTPCPS       18920            75            76    -25126.7      -24821.0  [<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>, <a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>]
5    SIggTestPerimeter         270           223           232       -21.1         -16.2  [<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>, <a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>]
6    SIgTestDatacenter         371           373           361         0.5          -2.7  [<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>, <a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>]
7        NSS-Financial           5            56            57        91.1          91.2  [<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>, <a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>]
8        NSS-Education         971          1010           958         3.9          -1.4  [<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>, <a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>]
9       NSS-EuroMobile         921           933           942         1.3           2.2  [<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>, <a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>]
10        NSS-USMobile         528           542           633         2.6          16.5  [<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>, <a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt"
```

But I need an output like this

```
                                                                                                                                             DFA
0    SigTestHTTP21kBin         217           219           453         0.9          52.0  <a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>
1   SigTestHTTP21kHtml         359           364           372         1.4           3.4   <a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>
2   SigTestHTTP21kText         380           376           378        -1.1          -0.6  
3     NSS-HTTP21Kdelay         378           380           378         0.5           0.0  
4          NSS-HTTPCPS       18920            75            76    -25126.7      -24821.0  
5    SIggTestPerimeter         270           223           232       -21.1         -16.2  
6    SIgTestDatacenter         371           373           361         0.5          -2.7  
7        NSS-Financial           5            56            57        91.1          91.2  
8        NSS-Education         971          1010           958         3.9          -1.4  
9       NSS-EuroMobile         921           933           942         1.3           2.2  
10        NSS-USMobile         528           542           633         2.6          16.5
```

I tried

```
f['DFA'].loc[0:2] = ['<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>','<a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>']
```

I get the following error:

```
 File "./some.py", line 50, in <module>
    f['DFA'].loc[0:2] = ['<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>','<a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.15.2-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1780, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.15.2-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1787, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.15.2-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1068, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.15.2-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2849, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.15.2-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/core/index.py", line 1402, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 134, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3812)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3692)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 696, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12299)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 704, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12250)
```

Comment: Sorry your new value is what a string or a list?

Comment: So you want to set all rows to the URL? it's tricky with lists, as it's an iterable it's expecting the length of the elements to match so the following would work: `f['DFA'] = [['<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>','<a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>']] * len(f)` this creates a list where it's repeated by the length of the df

Comment: im sorry its a set of string.........

Comment: Well I now don't understand your question, can you trim it down to just the essential problem and show your desired output clearly

Comment: Something like URL1 in column DFA one below other.
                        URL2

Comment: I want to see code not comments, I don't understand what you want, as I said before trim your code, show your errors and your desired output

Comment: Modified the qn with details.

Comment: So you just want the first row to take a list of urls and you want it to remain as a list of 2 urls? does `f['DFA'].iloc[0] = [['<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>','<a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>']]` work?

Comment: Im truly sorry, I had posted with error. I DO NOT need any List. Just URL's one below the other (as mentioned in the qn).

Comment: Sorry it's unbelievable how tedious this question is, do you understand how annoying it is to keep asking again and again what you want, even your last comment still isn't clear are you wanting a single row with 2 urls or 2 rows with a single url for each?

Comment: Im truly sorry. Need a single URL for each row one below the other.

Comment: This should work then `f['DFA'].iloc[0:2] = ['<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>','<a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>']`

Comment: You mean my last comment worked?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a list of values to multiple rows, with each value in a list to match specific rows then you need the lhs and rhs to match in length:

```
f['DFA'].iloc[0:2] = ['<a href="http://10.209.81.36/Binary_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Binary</a>','<a href="http://10.209.81.36/HTML_dfa_NSS_sorted_2464.txt">Html</a>']
```

This selects the first 2 rows using integer row based indexing